# I want to pull a number from one Excel column or row to another

Tags: microsoft-excel

So column a I have my bills unpaid

```
A                          B
___                        ___
Rent       800             Rent     0
Lights      50             Lights  50
Gas        100             Gas    100
Phone      100             Phone  100
          _____                  _____
          1050                   250


                                        Income    1500.00
                                        Bills     1050.00
                                        Remainder  450.00
```

Basically, in column B when I pay a bill, I will put a 0 in that line. Then,I want to take the bill total that I paid and subtract from my income. The remainder should be what is left after I paid all the bills.

Comment: What formula do you use for Bills

Comment: Think about the summary action, lower right. You have gross income and expected total bills. Both of those are relatively fixed. Beyond that, you want to track actual payments and their effect on what remains to be paid and how much earmarked money is still unspent. There are various items you can show and different ways to aggregate things. Yass's answer breaks out some of the detail to make things clearer. It's easy for accounting action to become confusing if you bury detail in aggregate numbers. You have nearly unlimited space in Excel. Don't be afraid to use it to keep detail separate.

Answer (score 1):

With your Data but you should write the numbers only in the cell without description to have the total payment:
`=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*(--B2:B5>0))`
The Remain `=1500-SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5*(--B2:B5>0))`

You can design your sheet differently:

```
  Column A      B            C           D             E             F        
 Description    Bills     Payment    Remain to pay   Income         1500
    Rent            800      800         0           Bills Total    1050
    Lights          50                   50          Payment Total   800
    Gas             100                 100          Remain          700
    Phone           100                 100          To be paid      250
```

In D2 write:  `=B2-C2`  you will have a result 0 when you write the payment
In F2 write:  `=SUM(B2:B5)`  you will have the total of Bills
In F3 write:  `=Sum(C2:C5)`  you will have the total of Payment
In F4 write:  `=F1-F3`       THE REMAIN
In F5 write:  `=Sum(D2:D5)`   To be paid

if your column A will be variant more than 5 rows you can use for total bills:
`=Sum(B2:B9999)` and just write the bills total nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Look you need some simple Mathematics to achieve what you are looking for.

Add 1 Col for Paid Value next to it Balance.
 
Write this for balance:

```
=B2-C2
```

```
=sum(B2:B5)
```

for col total for total bill amount.

```
=sum(C2:C5)
```

for col total of paid value.

```
=(B6-C6)
```

for remaining balance.